# Subversive Team share for existing projects

Tags: svn, subversive

I know this question has been asked a couple of times, but there's something that's not clear to me about the Team -> Share project dialog. Sorry about the repost :)

So I have this bunch of projects that are already managed by svn (svn directories are present) that I imported in Eclipse through the new project dialog. Everything works fine.

When using the Share project wizard, I select the SVN provider, the repository, and I go through the two following steps to a dire "Enter a commit comment" dialog. Now I don't want the plugin to make a commit, or any modification to the repository.

I tried to do this with another repo where I have read only access and got a 405 on an MKACTIVITY operation.

I tried with Subclipse, and it just casually tells me that the project is present on the repository and that it will now link it, thank you very much.

According to other answers there is a similar functionality in Subversion, so my questions are :

- Are the steps of the share project wizard different in Subclipse when he detects that the project exists ? If not is there any way to know that ?
- Do we just go through the commit, unchecking every file, and praying that the plugin doesn't svn add anything ?

**Precisions**

- The "enable automatic project share" option is ticked in the SVN General settings.
- I could use subclipse, but I'm just curious about how to do it in subversive, and I don't like the idea of changing plugins just because I couldn't figure out the share project dialog :)
- There are files in the projects that are not managed in svn, so checkout is not an easy option. They are quite huge projects and there's 8 of them.
- Usually the svn operations are handled with TortoiseSVN, but we use the eclipse plugin for history / comparisons

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  What is it that you are trying to do using the `Team -> Share` dialog?  That dialog is for adding a new project to a repository (which you don't need to do if your projects are already in SVN) or for reconnecting a project to the SVN repository if you have manually disconnected it (by killing all the local `.svn` folders), which hopefully you haven't done.

Comment: Yes maybe this is not too clear. I have a fresh install of Eclipse where I add projects that are already on the local drive, I think they've been checked out through Tortoise. They have their svn directories set. So the project is already in the repository, and already on the machine with its svn info available. I just want the Team provider to acknowledge this :) Right now it only shows offline options in the Team dialog (apply patch, share project)

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  Sadly, I only have Subclipse installed, and when I try it with a test project in that state (disconnected but with all SVN metadata intact) it just links the project with no fuss.

Comment: I have 4 projects checked out in a single directory, 3 of them are loaded by Subversive fine, but the larger one won't, it stays offline just like yours! Maybe its a performance problem ? It took a minute or so for the smaller ones to appear with SVN status. Do you have smaller projects to test with? Edit: manually removing and adding again the big project individually a couple times worked! I used the Root directory to load all projects at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with this re-occuring issue is the fact that the version of your svn clients is different.

Tortoise svn uses his own svn executable. Subversive uses his own svn executable and the executable on the command line is again, an other version.

Subversive cannot read .svn file of a new version. So when your SVN version of eclipse is i.e. 1.6 and your connector in eclipse is 1.5, subversive will not be able to read the .svn files.

The key is to match the different SVN implementations by version.

Comment: I think at this time the svn versions were matching, I'll have to retry it now (in the meantime I just switched to subclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Posting what worked for me in an answer, as I was experiencing the same thing - trying to use SVN features inside eclipse from a working-copy already checked out by TortoiseSVN on the filesystem. I had a root directory with 4 sub-folder (each one an eclipse project). On import'ing the projects, only 3 of them managed to use the SVN info contained on the file system. What did work in my case was deleting the non-working project and re-importing it (had to do a couple times until it worked)

Comment: Wow it's been a while since I logged in, I'll try the provided answers and try to accept the best one :)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me recently. For my case, the culprit was the different SVN client versions between TortoiseSVN and the SVN Connector in Eclipse. You can simply fix this by choosing the SVN Connector version in Eclipse:

Window - Preferences -> Team - SVN -> SVN Connector (Tab)

[image: Screen Snaps in Eclipse Settings]